# how to make a veriety of streaming URLs player in android with using listView

Tags: java, android, listview, video-streaming

I am trying to make an `app` which can `stream` radio channels using unique url for every `channel`.
i know how to make a `listView`, and using the `arrayAdapter`, and make a `media player`.
What i don't know is where to call the `media player` in the code, And how to assign a different `url` for a unique items in the `listView` when it tapped.

Comment: This is a bit broad. We're going to need it narrowed down to make sure our help is actually helpful to you.

Comment: @rmdan try this code on github.............https://github.com/LeonardoCardoso/Android-Link-Preview

Comment: thank you very much, that was helpful.